# Export Wordpress page to CSV from front end

Tags: php, csv, plugins, wordpress

I'm looking for a Wordpress plugin that takes a section of the page content - e.g. a price list - and exports it to CSV. So I can place a "Download CSV" link on the page that users can click.

If you know if a plugin that does this, or could be easily modified to do this, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Asking for recommendations or for us to find something for you is off-topic. It's up to you to find it and ask for help when you already have some code to work with.

Comment: Prior to posting this question I spent a good few hours googling for solutions and testing a bunch of plugins - but came up empty handed. I posted here as I was hoping others who've dealt with a similar problems might be able to point me in the right direction.

Comment: [Jay's example](http://dinetweb.altervista.org/2013/12/17/php-export-html-table-csv/) can be converted to a plugin: the button opens a new window passing its own URL and the script reads the page (`$url = $_GET['uri']`) and exports.

Comment: I agree with @brasofilo, however, the Jay's example needs to be reworked, it has some minor flaws, for example - it can export only  table with fixed `id` attribute and other small issues.

Comment: I managed to rework the dinetweb example into a custom plugin. Probably not the most robust plugin mind you, but it does the trick. Thanks for your help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code I wrote on the off chance it helps someone else:

```
add_action('wp', 'generate_csv');
function generate_csv()
{
    if ('csv' == (isset($_GET['format']) ? $_GET['format'] : null)) {
        $calendar_shortcode_id = get_field("calendar_shortcode_id");
        if($calendar_shortcode_id) {
            global $post;
            $shortcode = "[google-calendar-events id='$calendar_shortcode_id' type='list']";
            $html = do_shortcode($shortcode);
            $doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML($html);
            $titles = array();
            $table=$doc;
            $a=0;
            $delim = "";
            $csv="";
            $num_cols=5;
            foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('span') as $td) {
            if($a==0) {$delim = "";}
            if($a<$num_cols) { $csv .= $delim . '"' . $td->nodeValue. '"';
            $delim = ",";
            }
            if($a==($num_cols-1)) { $csv .= "\n";$a=-1;}
            $a++;
            }
            header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
            header("Content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$post->post_name.".csv");
            echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF"; // UTF-8 BOM
            echo utf8_decode($csv);
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```